# USB transfer speed vs charging power

Tags: usb, usb-pd

I know that a USB cable needs an e-marker chip to be able to charge over 3A.
What about the USB 3.2 SuperSpeed specs, e.g. 10 Gbps or 20 Gbps?

I ask because it seems that any cable with transfer speed of 10 Gbps or faster is also 5A capable, having the e-marker chip.

Is there a technical reason as to why there aren't cables SuperSpeed 10 Gbps or faster, but with no e-marker chip (that is, limited to 3A)? For example a USB 3.2 Gen 2 cable (20 Gbps) with no e-marker chip (60W max).

Comment: USB 10gbit is backwards compatible with existing USB 3 cables (at least officially), so most 10g cables don't have e-markers. 20g cables are different (USBC is required with extra lanes), so most are probably able to run higher current.

Answer (score 2):

The e-marker chip is just that: a marker. It can mark many different things, and 5A current carrying capability is just one of the things it can mark. It doesn't **have to**.

For example, I've been playing with custom USB-C cables for vendor-specific alternate modes. To enable those modes, the cable has to fulfill the requirements of the alternate mode, and has to be suitably marked. But it doesn't need to be marked for 5A capacity, since the mode doesn't require it.

USB-C is a very flexible spec, and generally speaking USB-C is a cable and connector spec, and is quite agnostic about what's sent over the cable *other than* over the configuration channel (CC). USB-C defines the configuration channel, and how it can be utilized for purposes that are outside of the USB-C standard itself. Simplifying things a bit, the only mandatory elements are the CC wires, ground and shielding. Everything else is optional.